# SQL how to do string replace for any SQL query data which comes out of column without using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, replace

I have a table with a column for different fruit names - Apple, Orange, Banana etc. These fruit names can have duplicates.

Right now if I do a SQL Select, I get the names as it is. I want to change the data so that every "Apple" gets replaced with "Sweet Apple" and every "Orange" gets replaced with "Mandarin".

I know I can use the `replace` function in my SQL queries. However I don't want to/can't modify my SQL queries. I was trying to leave changing the SQL as a last resort because that needs to be done on several different nodejs scripts.

I am wondering if there is some way in the database itself which can make it return these altered data automatically. Sort of like a filter / pipeline / constraint (I am not sure what to call it) which is set on a specific column of a table and makes it automatically do this replace function for any data which is queried from this table.

I would like an answer for mainly Postgres and MySQL and if possible for SQL Server too.

Comment: @squillman for now it's Postgres but I also have the same question for other databases. Should it be a separate question? I edited the question mentioning my database requirement. I am sorry if I messed up.

Comment: Yes, should be separate questions since there are frequently different implementations / syntaxes across each DBMS.

Comment: In any of the DBMS you tagged your question is a bit strange. You can't just decide to have a query to return a different value than what is stored. In all these cases you would need to do this using REPLACE. It could be done in a view or a query. ;But since you state you can't touch the queries you are stuck plain and simple.

Comment: @SeanLange Oh ok. I was trying to leave changing the SQL as a last resort because that needs to be done on several different nodejs scripts.

Comment: Perhaps getting your sql out of js scripts would be a good investment. If your sql was in stored procedures instead of pass through queries all you would have to do is update the procedures and everything else would just work.

Comment: Couldn't you just run an `UPDATE` on your existing data to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

No, the closest would be triggers on Insert and Update to replace the data as it comes in, but you cannot override data that is being queried without specifying it in the query. You can create a view that would show the replaced strings.

Answer (score 0):

It has its drawbacks, but you could do this:

Change the name of the Fruit column to something else, and then create a new Computed column that does the REPLACE you want on the newly-renamed Fruit column, and give this new column the name of the old column, so that all your existing queries will hit the new column.

Drawback is that any existing INSERT/UPDATE queries have to be changed to INSERT/UPDATE to the new name of the old column.

Answer (score 0):

Well, The Idea of a database is "storing values". So, if you are querying these values, you only have little options on modification.

Your expectation of handling is clearly up to your programming language. Whenever you output a value retrieved from the database, wrap it, filter it - return whatever you need instead of the stored value, i.e.:

```
public static string filter(value){
  if (value == "Apple")
     return "Sweet Apple";
  if (value == "Orange")
     return "Mandarine";

  return value;
}
```